# unresolved symbol with only dlmopen and not dlopen

Tags: multithreading, dll, linker, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I am using a shared library which has quite a few global variables,
used in almost
all the exported functions so the library functions are not thread safe.
My application creates multiple threads and each threads dynamically open this
library and to avoid using any synchronization between parallel calls
to the exported
functions, I copied the library multiple times with different names on disk with
each thread opening its own copy. To avoid this, now I am looking to use dlmopen instead but I am facing an issue.

When I use dlopen in my application to open a library, the application works fine

```
libHandle = dlopen(ip->pathname, (RTLD_LAZY |RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_DEEPBIND|RTLD_NODELETE));
```

When I use dlmopen instead in  the application, I am getting error:

```
ip->libHandle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, ip->pathname,
                (RTLD_LAZY |RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_DEEPBIND|RTLD_NODELETE));
```

The dlerror is:

```
error(libfoo.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteE)
```

Doing an nm does show the symbol undefined
U _ZTIN6google8protobuf11MessageLiteE

Question1: I am wondering how can I resolve this issue so I can use dlmopen.

The reason is because when one uses LM_ID_NEWLM a new empty namespace is created in the libc without any symbols. So the library should be self contained or relinked with any dependencies.

Question2: My main application exports some symbols which libfoo will use. Due to opening libfoo in new namespace, the symbols of main application are not visible to libfoo and hence it is not able to resolve them.
Is there any way to tell linker to create a new namespace NEWLM, by making replica of existing base namespace and than use dlmopen + lmid of newly created namespace to open libfoo with all other required symbols being already present?

Question3: Can I myself mmap the different section of libfoo and provide a pointer to the mmaped sections to libc. Means take the job of opening file and mmaping it out of libc and let it do the job of symbol resolution? That way I don't need to call dlopen at all and the multiple text section issue would be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I resolve this issue

When you use `dlopen`, the newly-loaded library can use all *already loaded* libraries to resolve its symbols. I am guessing that `libprotobuf.so` is one of such already-loaded libraries.

When you use `dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, ...)`, your newly-loaded library *must* be completely self-contained.

The fact that `dlmopen` fails tells you that it is not. You should relink `libfoo.so.0` against `libprotobuf.so` (and any other library it needs).

Use `ldd -r libfoo.so.0` to verify that all symbols in it are resolved. It is also a good idea to use `-Wl,--no-undefined` when linking `libfoo.so.0`.

**Update:**

> My main application exports some symbols which libfoo will use. Due to opening libfoo in new namespace, the symbols of main application are not visible to libfoo and hence it is not able to resolve them.

That is expected behavior. If there a reasonably small number of such symbols, you can explicitly register them with `libfoo`:

```
void *h = dlmopen(...);
void (*init)(void *, void *) = dlsym(h, 'init');
(*init)(&main_fn1, &main_fn2);
```

> Is there any way to tell linker to create a new namespace NEWLM, by making replica of existing base namespace and than use dlmopen + lmid of newly created namespace to open libfoo with all other required symbols being already present?

I don't believe so. It's an interesting idea. Feel free to open a feature request in [glibc bugzilla](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=glibc).

> With dlmopen it seems plausible (although max limit of 16)

It seems to me that while 16 instances of `libfoo` is better than one, you are still severely limited on this path, and it would be much better to rewrite `libfoo` to not use globals in the first place.

**Update 2:**

> Can I myself mmap the different section of libfoo and provide a pointer to the mmaped sections to libc

You could, if GLIBC [bug 11767](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767) was implemented. But it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Relinking libfoo with libproto and all other required library is possible. But I have a bigger problem. My main application exports some symbols which libfoo will use. Due to opening libfoo in new namespace, the symbols of main application are not visible to libfoo and hence it is not able to resolve them. Is there any way to tell linker to create a new namespace NEWLM, by making replica of existing base namespace and than use dlmopen + lmid of newly created namespace to open libfoo with all other required symbols being already present?

Comment: The crux of this activity is to avoid multiple copies of the text section caused by copying the same library multiple times because each copy instance would have different inode number. Compare this to the situation when the inode is same. In this case the text section would be shared among each dlopen instance while each have its own private data copy. Unfortunately dlopen is not allowing multiple open because the libc code checks if the inode is already opened in the current namespace. With dlmopen it seems plausible (although max limit of 16) but the empty namespace is giving me issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s). I agree that going dlmopen way is also not a complete solution but somewhat better. Also I agree, changing libfoo would be most apt path.  I have a (hopefully last) question though. Its just a navie question, pardon me I don't have enough knowledge on linking/loading. Can I myself mmap the different section of libfoo and provide a pointer to the mmaped sections to libc. Means take the job of opening file and mmaping out of libc and let it do the job of symbol resolution? That way I don't need to call dlopen at all and the multiple text section issue would be solved

Comment: So `dlmopen` can only create a "fresh" namespace? There is no simple way to base it off the existing namespace, correct (in my case I wanted to dlmopen stuff but make some already linked shared lib unavailable for the dlmopened lib, but keep everything else intact).

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to tell linker to create a new namespace NEWLM, by making replica of existing base namespace and than use dlmopen + lmid of newly created namespace to open libfoo with all other required symbols being already present?

Here is the way I solved a similar problem:

1. Dynamically load protobuf into a new namespace:

   ```
   void* pb_handle = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libprotobuf.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   ```
2. Grab the namespace id:

   ```
   Lmid_t lmid;
   dlinfo(dl_handle, RTLD_DI_LMID, &lmid);
   ```
3. Open foo into your new protobuf namespace:

   ```
   void* foo_handle = dlmopen(lmid, “libfoo.so.0”, RTLD_LAZY);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Do `dlerror()` after `dlmopen()` to check whether this dll loaded.
(check the return value of dlmopen() is nullptr?)

You may notice that something like address sanitizer would place some UNDEFINED symbol in .so library and make implement in entry ELF file (which the `int main()` placed)

To check this, using:

```
readelf -s exe_main |grep __asan_init
readelf -s libfoo.so |grep __asan_init
```

In my system I can see that below:

```
[vrqq@rhel]$ readelf -s ./out/libfoo.so |grep __asan_init
    26: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __asan_init
   226: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __asan_init
[vrqq@rhel]$ readelf -s ./out/exe_main |grep __asan_init
  1279: 00000000002fe430    96 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 __asan_init
  5017: 00000000002fe430     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 .annobin___asan_init.star
  5018: 00000000002fe490     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 .annobin___asan_init.end
  9044: 00000000002fe430    96 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 __asan_init
```